# read comma-separated input with `scanf()`

Tags: c, csv, input, file-io, scanf

I have the following input:

```
AG23,VU,Blablublablu,8
IE22,VU,FooBlaFooBlaFoo,3
and so on...
```

I want it to "parse" with `scanf()` using some code like this:

```
char sem[5];
char type[5];
char title[80];
int value;

while(scanf("%s,%s,%s,%d", sem, type, title, &value) == 4) {
 //do something with the read line values
}
```

But the execution of the code gives me: `illegal instruction`

How would you read a comma-separated file like this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The comma is not considered a whitespace character so the format specifier `"%s"` will consume the `,` and everything else on the line writing beyond the bounds of the array `sem` causing undefined behaviour. To correct this you need to use a scanset:

```
while (scanf("%4[^,],%4[^,],%79[^,],%d", sem, type, title, &value) == 4)
```

where:

- `%4[^,]` means read at most four characters or until a comma is encountered.

Specifying the width prevents buffer overrun.

Comment: Note that, even if no overrun occurs, the following `,` in the *format* won’t match.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
scanf("%d%*c");  // to suppress any character you want to skip taking input

suppose scanf("%d%*c%d",&a,&b);  // i/p is 31,42  %*is used for suppression
o/p: 3142

it may be any character /  ,  .  .......

Answer (score -1):

The problem that you are having is because when you say

```
 scanf("%s,%s,%s,%d", sem, type, title, &value)
```

what happens is that you are trying doing is that you are fitting all the line into the first string which is just 5 characters. Therefore the **`sem[5]` overflows**, and soes all sorts of funny things. To avoid this problem, I tried using the expression `%[^,]`, but it is not quite working. The best bet is to use something like

```
while(scanf("%s%c%s%c%s%c%d", sem, &ch, type, &ch, title, &ch, &value) != EOF)
```

Then you can just discard the `ch`. However bear in mind that is better to use other functions to reading input such as `getchar()`, and things like that, which are much faster and safer in some sense.

Comment: The problem with your "best bet" is that it doesn't quite work either.