# php sscanf and comma character

Tags: php, scanf

I have a trouble with [PHP sscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) function and comma character. I need to extract 4 values, as this working example does:

```
<?php
$format = '%s %s, blabla %ih blabla %ih';
$input = 'blabla 08-06-2016 blabla 14h blabla 17h';
$result = sscanf($input, $format);
var_dump($result);
```

output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'blabla' (length=10)
  1 => string '08-06-2016' (length=10)
  2 => int 14
  3 => int 17
```

but my real example involves one comma character, and I do not get it to work:

```
<?php
$format = '%s %s, blabla %ih blabla %ih';
$input = 'blabla 08-06-2016, blabla 14h blabla 17h';
$result = sscanf($input, $format);
var_dump($result);
```

output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'blabla' (length=10)
  1 => string '08-06-2016,' (length=11)
  2 => null
  3 => null
```

It's very simple, but I can't find the solution... Is comma a reserved word?

**UPDATE 1:**

Sorry, I forgot to mention this:
I wish to use the string template stored on $format as a template to sprintf too: If I modify it including regexp, it will not be sprintf compatible, am I wrong?
I have supossed that same string template can serve to two directions: wrapping and unwrapping: very useful!... maybe is not possible with a comma involved?

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have a constraint that I forgot to mention... please look at UPDATE 1

Comment: can you expand on how you want to use `sprintf`? please show an example so I can have a better idea

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue [read comma-separated input with scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091284/read-comma-separated-input-with-scanf).

`$format = '%s %20[^,], blabla %ih blabla %ih';` or some other max length, the 20 is arbitrary since I have no context in your application.