# Comma between the two integers during the input

Tags: c, input, scanf, format-string

What exactly happens if I do the following

```
scanf("%d,%d", &i, &j);
```

and provide an input which causes the matching failure? Will it store garbage into `j`?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Looks like a duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091284/read-comma-separated-input-with-scanf

Comment: [why not read the manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you not understood the function's behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input has to *exactly* match the supplied *format* for `scanf()` to be success.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fsacnf()`, (*emphasis mine*)

> Except in the case of a `%` specifier, the input item (or, in the case of a `%n` directive, the
>   count of input characters) is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier. **If
>   the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this
>   condition is a matching failure.** Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, **the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the format argument that has not already received a conversion result.** If this object
>   does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
>   in the object, the behavior is undefined.

and,

> When all directives
>   have been executed, or **if a directive fails (as detailed below), the function returns.**

So, consolidating the above cases,

- For an input like `100, 200`, the scanning will be success. Both `i` and `j` will hold the given values, `100` and `200`, respectively.
- For an input like `100 - 200`, the scanning will fail (matching failure) and the content of `j` will remain unchanged, i.e., `j` is not *assigned* any value by `scanf()` operation.

Word of advice: always check the return value of `scanf()` function family to ensure the success of the function call.